# Floating animation just flows ease when I change browser's tab and get back

Tags: css, browser, css-animations

here is my problem:

I have made a smooth floating animation that translate a container into Y axis 1% up and then gets back to the original state infinitely.

The problem is, inside that container I have several components that follow the same movement, but, when I first enter the webpage, the animation don't play smothly, it appers to be going kind of frame by frame, for example: it's very noticeable the elements are going 2px up,then 2px up,then 2px up then down.

BUT, when I change for another browser tab and then get back to my webpage tab, the animation plays easely and fluidly. I don't know what this can be, any guesses?

Here is my css animation:

```
.test1 {
    animation: tilt1 1.7s alternate 3.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes tilt1 {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-20%);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(-19.5%);
    }
}
```

The component original state is translateY(-20%)

For the html code you can just imagine it's a square div, 50% screen height, with some text centralized in it.

I don't think it's a code problem, because it does work as I want (but just when I change tab and get back).